# When predicting new dataset should I use scaler.fit_trasform(new_dataset) or scaler.transform(new_dataset)

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression, prediction, joblib

final_poly_converter = PolynomialFeatures(degree=3,include_bias=False)

final_poly_features = final_poly_converter.fit_transform(X)

final_scaler = StandardScaler()

scaled_X = final_scaler.fit_transform(final_poly_features)

from sklearn.linear_model import Lasso

final_model = Lasso(alpha=0.004943070909225827,max_iter=1000000)

final_model.fit(scaled_X,y)

from joblib import dump,load

dump(final_model,'lasso_model.joblib')

dump(final_poly_converter,'lasso_poly_coverter.joblib')

dump(final_scaler,'scaler.joblib')

loaded_converter = load('lasso_poly_coverter.joblib')

loaded_model = load('lasso_model.joblib')

loaded_scaler = load('scaler.joblib')

campaign = [[149,22,12]]

transformed_data = loaded_converter.fit_transform(campaign)

scaled_data = loaded_scaler.transform(transformed_data)# fit_transform or only transform

loaded_model.predict(scaled_data)

The output values change when I use fit_transform() and when I use transform()

Answer (score 0):

You should always use `fit_transform` on your train and `transform` on test and further predictions. If you refit your scaler on test pool you would have a different feature distribution in your test set vs train set which is something you don't want to happen. Think of scaler params that you fit as part of the model parameters. Naturally you fit all the parameters on the training set and then you don't change them on the test evaluation/prediction.